# Get recursive list of svn:ignore'd files

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I have an existing project repo which I use for project A, and has some files and directories excluded from it using svn:ignore. I want to start another project (project B), in a new repo, with approximately the same files ignored in it.

How can I get a list of all files in the repo with svn:ignore set on them and the value of that property? I am using Ubuntu, so sed and grep away if that helps.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
svn propget -R svn:ignore
```

Output looks like:

```
path/to/dir1 - *.exe
*~

path/to/dir2 - #*

path/to/dir3 - ...etc...
```

Comment: I found that this in combination with svn propget -R svn:global-ignores gives a more exhaustive list.

Comment: Well the output of this particular SVN command is not the easiest to parse, but I'm sure it can be done with advanced shell/awk/sed.  Still, what were they thinking when they designed that output?

Answer (score 20):

```
svn status --no-ignore | grep "I  "
```

Comment: does this how all ignore files, or just those that are altered?

Comment: Beware, this could conceivably fail if a filename contains "I ". I think grepping on "^I " is safer.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
  svn st --no-ignore | grep '^I'
```

to find the externals.

if you need to find all the svn directories, try:

```
  find . -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 dirname
```

You could try

```
 find . -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 dirname | xargs svn pg svn:ignore
```

to get all the externals, but the output will look something like:

```
docs - _*

mwbuild - _*
local-settings
*.pyc
```

i.e., not split along line boundaries. Maybe more sed/awk magic would make that behave?

Comment: Ack, sorry. I didn't notice when I wrote my answer that you'd described the `propget` and its output.